# In this code, why are 1/2 and 0.5 behaving differently?

Tags: c++

[image: Image for the code in C++]

In this code, why are the outputs for `1/2` and `0.5` different?

Comment: Please don't post images of code, least of all as links. Copy-paste code (or any text really) as *text* into the question. And please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And the difference between `1 / 2` and `0.5` (or `1.0 / 2.0`) should have been taught by your text-book. If you don't have one then [here's a list of good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282). You will save yourself a lot of time and problems if you invest in one or two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 and 2 are integers, and use integer based division (1/2=0)
You want to use 1.0 / 2.0 (resulting in 0.5)